# StayOpen="False" with inherited popups

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

I have a popup modal that is using StaysOpen="False" to automatically close when you click outside of the popup. However the popup contains buttons that open new popup windows and I want to keep the parent popup (the one using the StaysOpen attribute) open.

Currently what is happening is you click a button inside the popup and new popup appears, the parent one stays open (which is intended). But when you close one of the child popups the parent one closes.

I need the parent popup to only close when focus is lost on anything outside of itself OR the child popups.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `bool` property to data bind to the [`Popup.IsOpen` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then you can open and close it whenever you like:

XAML

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}">
    <TextBlock Text="I'm a Popup" />
</Popup>
```

C#

```
// Open Popup
IsPopupOpen = true;
// Close Popup
IsPopupOpen = false;
```

Comment: How does this get triggered if the user clicks anywhere outside of the popup?