# Popup doesn't open if StaysOpen="False"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I change StaysOpen to "True", the popup shows up, but it doesn't close when you click outside of it, so that's not what I want.

Here is the relevant XAML code:

```
<Border x:Name="popupPlacementTarget">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:PopupBehavior>
            <local:PopupBehavior.Popup>
                <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupPlacementTarget}"
                       Placement="MousePoint"
                       StaysOpen="False">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SomeContent}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeContentTemplate}" />
                </Popup>
            <local:PopupBehavior.Popup>
        </local:PopupBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Border>
```

And here is the PopupBehavior code:

```
public class PopupBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Popup", typeof(Popup), typeof(PopupBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Popup)));

    #endregion Dependency Properties

    #region Properties

    public Popup Popup
    {
        get { return (Popup)this.GetValue(PopupProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(PopupProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Protected Methods

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.MouseDown += this.OnMouseDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        this.AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= this.OnMouseDown;
    }

    #endregion Protected Methods

    #region Private Methods

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var popup = this.Popup;
        if (popup == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

Any idea why my popup won't show up with StaysOpen="False"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [StayOpen="False" with inherited popups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464557/stayopen-false-with-inherited-popups). Please see my answer from this linked question for a solution to your problem.

Comment: I do not feel like the answer to the question you linked is applicable to this question.

Comment: Is your posted xaml complete? Currently it looks like you're adding the `Behavior` as a child to the `Border` than within `<i:Interaction.Behaviors>...</i:Interaction.Behaviors>`

Comment: That's a typo, it is within interaction behaviors. I'll edit.

Comment: @Kelsie, it is rare that you get a question that is exactly the same as another. The point is that there is a working solution for you in the linked post, if you would only just try it.

Comment: It's not a working solution to this problem. It's not really even a working solution to the problem you answered. In both cases, the answer is far from what was actually asked. The other question, however, was doing something pretty goofy, and it's obvious in the context why it was closing (the focus was ending up on the other popup), so manually managing the state might be necessary. In this case, this should just be working, and there is nothing goofy going on. There's no reason I should have to manage this manually.

Comment: Personally, I think it would be a lot more useful if you at least explained *why* his popup was closing to him in your answer before offering a workaround.

Comment: @Kelsie, Sheridan's trying to help, but may have come off as curt.  His answer is ok.  But, the WPF Pop Up behaviour depends on some incidental factors that are not readily apparent.  Rachel may be along to give an answer, but if not, read her article.  http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/

Comment: @GarryVass, I appreciate the link. I think what she is doing in there is more akin to a small dialog than a popup. A popup is really what I want here. Do you have any further insight with regards to the incidental factors that are not readily apparent?

Comment: Focus, pointer events, window position, Command Manager, input bindings, even SECURITY are all actors.

Comment: I suspect that focus has something to do with this, given the StaysOpen property's affect on this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was an ancestor that was indiscriminately grabbing capture on mouse down. Everything is working correctly now that I've corrected this issue.

As an aside, I was able to hack around this problem by setting StaysOpen="True", inheriting Popup, and hooking in to the global mouse events within the derived Popup. When the popup opens, I'd attach the handler to the global input events. Then, when an event is received, I'd filter it such that I'm only responding to left mouse button down events. In handling this event, I'd close the popup and detach the event if the mouse is not hovering the popup. It worked, but it is obviously a dirty hack, and I'm happy that I got this working without it.